# bundling css works but fonts not loading

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I have the following folders structure in my MVC site:

> -- Content -- Notebook -- css
>
> -- Content -- Notebook -- fonts

Content is directly under the root for the site.  In my css folder i have a file which has a relative path

> url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.0.3')

My bundle currently looks like:

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/bundles/Content/Notebook/css").Include(
        "~/Content/Notebook/css/animate.css",
        "~/Content/Notebook/css/font.css",
        "~/Content/Notebook/css/font-awesome.min.css",
        "~/Content/Notebook/css/app.css"
));
```

This is rendered using

```
@Styles.Render("~/bundles/Content/Notebook/css")
```

this works for the css files, but the font file isn't loading, i see that it is looking for it here `http://localhost/MySite/bundles/Content/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.0.3`

I saw that and then tried to change my bundle name to

> ~/Content/Notebook/css

thinking that would get the relative path to work also, if i remove the "bundles" from the name,
but doing that causes the css files not to load.  Why wouldn't the css files load?  If I had the word "bundles" back to the name it works again.  Also any idea on how to get the fonts to load along with the bundle?

Comment: You could see this thread about fonts not rendering properly. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32692151/fonts-are-not-rendered-correctly-in-release-mode-but-is-working-on-debug-mode-i?answertab=votes#tab-top

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you do this:

```
url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.0.3')
```

you are referring to the fonts via a relative path. If you then put your CSS bundle at `/bundles/Content/Notebook/css` it will look in `bundles/content/fonts` since that's combination of your relative path and where the browser see your css-file.

A few possible options (either):

- Change your bundle path:

  ```
  bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/Notebook/css") ...
  (the reason your css files didn't load when you removed bundles was that you didn't change the name of the stylebundle)
  ```

  and

  ```
  @Styles.Render("~/Content/Notebook/css")
  ```
- Reference your fonts with an absolute path:

  ```
  url('/Content/notebook/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.0.3')
  ```

Comment: I tried the 1st option, changing the StyleBundle name to ~/Content/Notebook/css and using the same for teh render, but that does not load my css.  it then looks for everything at http://localhost/MySite/Content/Notebook/css/?v=3VfY7DPwOdVyXqP6Gz8G1MTxMp6VFbReLjeUU0eWRSU1  I thought that would work, but i'm still not sure why simply removing the word bundle stopped it from working.

Comment: I ended up changing the css file to reference the fonts as url('../Content/notebook/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.0.3') and left my bundle names alone, that got it working.  Still not use though why when I changed the bundle name the css stopped working, even though it was the same name i used in the render call.

Comment: You could see this thread about fonts not rendering properly. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32692151/fonts-are-not-rendered-correctly-in-release-mode-but-is-working-on-debug-mode-i?answertab=votes#tab-top